# How to declare for loop in swift?

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift

I am facing some problem in writing a for loop in Swift.
Can anybody guess the problem in this

```
 var sublayers : Array <AnyObject>= [self.previewLayer.sublayers]
        var subLayersCount: NSInteger = sublayers.count, currentSublayer = 0
        var featuresCount :NSInteger = features.count, currentFeature = 0;

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey: kCATransactionDisableActions)
        var layerTemp : CALayer = CALayer()
        for layerTemp  in sublayers{
            if(layerTemp.name  == "FaceLayer"){
                layerTemp.hidden = true
            }
```

I am trying to check the layers in sublayers. 
`layertemp` is of `CAlayer` and `sublayers` is of `AnyObject`.

It gives me an error:
`Constant layerTemp is inferred to be of AnyObject which is unexpected.`

Can anybody shed some light over this.

Equivalent code in obj-c is:

```
NSArray *sublayers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.previewLayer sublayers]];
NSInteger sublayersCount = [sublayers count], currentSublayer = 0;
NSInteger featuresCount = [features count], currentFeature = 0;

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

// hide all the face layers
for ( CALayer *layer in sublayers ) {
    if ( [[layer name] isEqualToString:@"FaceLayer"] )
        [layer setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: why did you add this line of code: `var layerTemp : CALayer = CALayer()`?

Comment: What on earth is “Swift C”?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing

```
var layerTemp : CALayer = CALayer()
for layerTemp  in sublayers{
```

with

```
//for layerTemp in sublayers as CALayer[] { // No longer works after Beta 3...
for layerTemp in sublayers as [CALayer] { // New sugar
```

the trick is you have to cast the array, not the element, whose type will always be inferred. This will *not* work:

```
for layerTemp as CALayer in sublayers { // doesn't compile
```

whilst this won't work because of type safety:

```
for layerTemp:CALayer in sublayers { // fails if sublayers is not [CALayer]
```

Comment: thanx. the solution works. Thanx for making me understand it.

Comment: thnx for the tip. I had tried it before. But i was type casting the element not array.